# faster INSERT INTO InnoDB table with composite PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb, primary-key, mariadb-10.5

I have a simple `tag_map`

```
CREATE TABLE tag_map
(
article_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
tag_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(tag_id),
PRIMARY KEY(article_id,tag_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The table is quite big (over 900 million rows). Obviously, `INSERT`ing into the empty table is quite fast, but when I add more rows, it takes a long time (since it needs to check for duplicates).

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tag_map (article_id,tag_id)
    SELECT article_id,tag_id FROM t1 WHERE article_id>0 AND tag_id>0
```

I did not run a side-by-side benchmark, but `ARIA` table is about 2-3 times faster for adding more rows.

I wonder if there are tricks to make `InnoDB` faster for this?

The relevant configs are

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things that each *might* speed it up:

- Add secondary keys *after* building the table.  That is, leave off `INDEX(tag_id)` and do an `ALTER` to add the index later.
- Sort and de-dup the incoming data.  That is

  ```
    INSERT INTO ...
        SELECT DISTINCT ...
            ORDER BY article_id, tag_id;
  ```

The `IGNORE` requires a lookup to verify that the row is not already there.  `DISTINCT` has the same effect, but is done in bulk, not one row at a time.

What is the relative size of the Aria table vs InnoDB?

In my experience, "tags" should not be normalized.  That is, I would simply have `(article_id, tag)`, not tag_id linking to another table.  That extra JOIN costs something.

Another tip:  If you will be sorting articles for display, especially with LIMIT and OFFSET, there are certain other inefficiencies.  I discuss this in [*Lists*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists) .  (That talks about "topics" in place of "tags".)

Comment: I don't follow. You are talking about the `INSERT INTO` empty table? My problem is when adding more rows. I need `INDEX(tag_id)` and `IGNORE` to skip duplicate rows (the rows that already exist in `tag_map` not duplicates in `t1` to be filtered by `DISTINCT`). The InnoDB table is about 1.5 times larger than the ARIA table.

Comment: @Googlebot - Sorry, both of my suggestions assume an empty table.

Comment: FYI, for a 1.5 billion-row table, InnoDB's ibd file is 141.7GB, Aria's MAD 13.6GB, and MAI 36.4GB. Thus, the exact answer is InnoDB table is almost 3 times larger.

Comment: @Googlebot - Thanks.  2x to 3x is what I have measured many times for InnoDB :: MyISAM.  So, I guess Aria is somewhat similar to MyISAM.

Comment: I have experimented a lot. MyISAM is slightly smaller than Aria. This is the biggest difference between the size of InnoDB and MyISAM/ARIA since there are two small indexed columns. I store `mediumtext` tables by Aria, and the difference is less than 1.5 times. There is not much storage benefit, but reading from Aria on HDD is 10 times faster than InnoDB.